# Login function doesn't work first time after cookies are cleared

Tags: php, mysql

The login system below works fine.  However, when the cookies are cleared from the Chrome browser, it does not work the first time a user logs in.  It works from the second time on up after the cookies are cleared.

Any ideas why the login is not working the first time after cookies are cleared from Chrome?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();             
        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {
        show_loginform();
    }


} else
{
    show_userbox();         
}   
?>
```

The login form function:

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{
    echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php">  

    <div class="usernameformtext"><label title="Username">Username: </label></div> 
    <div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" id="username" /></div> 

    <div class="passwordformtext"><label title="Password">Password: </label></div> 
    <div class="passwordformfield"><input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /></div> 

    <div class="registertext"><a href="http://www...com/.../register.php" title="Register">Register</a></div> 
    <div class="lostpasswordtext"><a href="http://www...com/.../lostpassword.php" title="Lost Password">Lost password?</a></div> 

  <p class="loginbutton"><input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" ';
    if ($disabled == true)
    {
        echo 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    echo ' /></p></form>';     
}
```

The login functions:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{

    if (isset($_SESSION['loginid']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        return true; // the user is loged in
    } 
    else
    {
        return false; // not logged in
    }

    return false;

}

function checkLogin($u, $p)
{
global $seed; // global because $seed is declared in the header.php file

    if (!valid_username($u) || !valid_password($p) || !user_exists($u))
    {
        return false; // the name was not valid, or the password, or the username did not exist
    }

    //Now let us look for the user in the database.
    $query = sprintf("
        SELECT loginid 
        FROM login 
        WHERE 
        username = '%s' AND password = '%s' 
        AND disabled = 0 AND activated = 1 
        LIMIT 1;", mysql_real_escape_string($u), mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($p . $seed)));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    // If the database returns a 0 as result we know the login information is incorrect.
    // If the database returns a 1 as result we know  the login was correct and we proceed.
    // If the database returns a result > 1 there are multple users
    // with the same username and password, so the login will fail.
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1)
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        // Login was successfull
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // Save the user ID for use later
        $_SESSION['loginid'] = $row['loginid'];
        // Save the username for use later
        $_SESSION['username'] = $u;
        // Now we show the userbox
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: same problem here! (with Firefox)- did you find a solution by now?

Answer (score 0):

Your session data is lost I guess. http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/session-cookies-used-for.html